# Identify shared folders with Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices

Is there a query or data element accessible using the Graph API that will allow you to distinguish a shared mailbox from a normal user in o365?  I normally want to only sync users if they have certain licenses but also include shared mailboxes (which do not require a license).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Your question is lacking sufficient detail to help the community help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Marc

Comment: As I am a new user I cannot edit the question Marc. Could you add the below: 
I have read the Graph API documentation and believe there is no data element that identifies that a 'user' is actually a shared mailbox.  However it seems odd if the only way to identify a shared mailbox is through PowerShell. So I am asking if any other users have needed to so this and found a way. I have already found that shared mailboxes may or may not have active or deleted licenses, so I cannot use that to identify them.

Comment: Interesting, you should be able to edit your own question. Do you get an error when you visit https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50462862/edit?

Answer (score 0):

A User and a Mailbox are two different things. A User is an account managed by Azure Active Directory, a Mailbox is an email destination managed by Exchange Online.

If you're asking how to determine which users have access to a given mailbox, this is not available through Microsoft Graph. You would need to use a different mechanism to determine a mailboxes configuration; the most common being Exchange Web Services or PowerShell (which is most likely using EWS behind the scenes).

Comment: No I am not trying to identify which users have access to a given mailbox. Only to be able to distinguish in the data returned by the Graph API, which is a user and which is a shared mailbox. In the data returned  by the API there is no apparent difference between a user and a shared mailbox. I'll taka another look at EWS though I couldn't see anything in the API to suggest it could do this either. Powershell definitely can, but embedding that in an application is not an attractive option.